# Installing a site with composer

Tags: composer

I installed and created a Drupal site using Composer and the template in https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project. I put everything I'd done in a [git repository](https://github.com/rukayaj/ssp).

On a another machine, I cloned the repository and used `composer install`. It seems Composer doesn't copy the files in the web/core directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the output from the Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was just something strange about the directory I was using. When I swapped to a different directory and did a fresh clone and did composer install it all worked as expected. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe core is not in you `composer.json` file?
So under the require section in your `composer.json` you should add:
`"drupal/core": "8.4",`

Another option would be to run `composer require drupal/core` in CLI (Command Line Interface)